# aws- update R version

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, epel

I need to install some packages that require R>=3.5. I am in a bash console of a SageMaker instance.

```
sh-4.2$ sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo "epel" list available | grep "R-core"
R-core.x86_64                               3.6.0-1.el7                     epel
R-core-devel.x86_64
```

When I run:

```
sh-4.2$ sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo "epel" install R
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper, versionlock
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: R-devel = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: R-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath-devel = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: R-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-java = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: R-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: R-core-devel = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: R-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-java-devel = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: R-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package R-java.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package R-java.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: R-core = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: R-java-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package libRmath-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libRmath-devel.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath = 3.6.0-1.el7 for package: libRmath-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xdg-utils for package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre2-8.so.0()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtk8.5.so()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: pcre2-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package libRmath.x86_64 0:3.4.1-1.52.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libRmath.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: xdg-utils
Error: Package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcre2-8.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtk8.5.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tk-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tcl-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: pcre2-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Why does it say "Finished Dependency Resolution" if it needs other packages?
How can I include/add those packages that this is asking for?

Thanks.